# Using batch for processing Text file

Tags: batch-file, line

I am new to batch scripting and  would like to process my input file with the content :

```
MD5 hash of sample.js,
81f87dd81ef88f59a57d95d9ede5f92e
MD5 hash of searchReplace.js,
3493b216e1024f0d6de417ef6c8b3962
MD5 hash of Select Anything.js,
009f2b911b50550502b87aeeeb969b55
```

The output should look like :

```
MD5 hash of sample.js,81f87dd81ef88f59a57d95d9ede5f92e
MD5 hash of searchReplace.js,3493b216e1024f0d6de417ef6c8b3962
MD5 hash of Select Anything.js,009f2b911b50550502b87aeeeb969b55

 Can someone please help me out with it ?
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "info_file=.\example1.txt"

for /f "useback tokens=* delims=" %%a in ("%info_file%") do (
    set "line=%%a"
    if "!line:~0,3!" EQU "MD5" (
        set "to_echo=!line!"
    ) else (
        set "to_echo=!to_echo!,!line!"
        echo !to_echo!
    )
)

endlocal
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply :ProcessFile
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "useback tokens=* delims=" %%a in ("%input%") do (
    set "line=%%a"
    if "!line:~0,3!" EQU "MD5" (
  set "to_echo=!line!"
    ) else (
       set "to_echo=!to_echo!,!line!"
       echo !to_echo!
    )
)>"%outfile%"

endlocal But the output in the input and output file looks like MD5 hash of Profiling.js,,8c77ed0fede766052fbff8c94f6d79dd . I have more files so need it for all of them and there is an additional comma.

Comment: Also I would like to understand the logic of if "!line:~0,3!" EQU "MD5" ? If i don't know how many lines I have , what can i use instead of !line:~0,3!" ?

Comment: @manishahlawat  - ahaa there's additional comma in the output?

Comment: Comma issue is resolved and i can get the output as intended, thanks a lot to you but  - I would like to understand the logic of if "!line:~0,3!" EQU "MD5" ? If i don't know how many lines I have , what can i use instead of !line:~0,3!" ? –

Comment: `!line:~0,3!` extracts the first three characters of the current `line` (see `set /?`). (`If "!line:~0,3!" EQU "MD5"` = `if the line starts with `MD5`). It has nothing to do with the total number of lines in the file.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
@echo off
setlocal

call :procFile < input.txt > output.txt
goto :EOF


:procFile
   set /P "line1="
   if errorlevel 1 exit /B
   set /P "line2="
   echo %line1%%line2%
goto procFile
```

---

You may also read the file via a `for /F` command this way:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "line="
(for /F "delims=" %%a in (input.txt) do (
   if not defined line (
      set "line=%%a"
   ) else (
      echo !line!%%a
      set "line="
   )
)) > output.txt
```

Comment: Mmmm... It worked?